# Exporting 3D geometry from PostGIS 2.0

Tags: qgis, postgis, 3d, export

I have a table containing 3D geometry in a PostGIS 2.0 database (the geometry is of type `LINESTRING Z`).

I need to get the geometry out and into a DXF, DGN or 3D Shapefile. What is the easiest way to do this?

(I was sure I had achieved this via QGIS before, but it seems to remove the `Z` value and produce only a 2D file when attempting a 'Save As ...' from a PostGIS layer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** *this is an old answer, tests with current versions might reveal different results*

GDAL is able to do this. The following command creates a 3D Shapefile:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "~/myshape" PG:"user={user} password={pass} dbname={dbname} host={host}" {table}
```

QGIS is not able to handle 3D geometries. I would be very surprised, if it would be able to transform 3D information from one format to another.

Comment: Starting from QGIS 2.10 https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog210/index.html#feature-new-geometry-engine 3D support has been improved continuously